# How do I open publisher at 75% or larger page view?

Tags: default-settings, microsoft-publisher

When I open a Publisher document in my Microsoft 365, it never opens at 100% of its size.  In fact, it usually opens at 43%-63%.  I would be satisfied with the default of 75%, but I want to be the one to determine how it opens.  It is only a few clicks to enlarge it, but it's a few extra clicks every day to add to the other "few extra clicks" that I can't solve with the default.  This is, after all, why we can set default settings, correct?